# Установка изображения для checkbox без обязательного label

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, checkbox

У меня есть проект, где иногда `checkbox`'ы не имеют соответствующих `label`'ов. Единственный способ установки произвольного изображения для `checkbox`, который я нашёл, была установка изображения для `label:before` для соответствующего `label`, который имеет значение `for` с атрибутом `id` `checkbox`'a.

Если какой-либо способ CSS (по крайней мере, с хаками) установки произвольного изображения для `checkbox`'a без изменения разметки? `input[type="checkbox"]:before` работает только в Chrome.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44841873/1548895

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственный способ, который я нашёл, который работает везде кроме IE для Desktop (работает в IE для Windows Phone) через CSS-свойство `appearance`:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background-color: red;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: А добавлять label display: none - не выход?

Comment: Я не хочу менять разметку. И зачем мне `label` там, где он сам по себе не нужен?

Comment: А что в вашем ответе должно позеленеть? Я в своем FF53 вижу обычный checkbox и ни чего зеленого :Р

Comment: @Visman В FF54 (Windows 10 Pro x64) у меня работает.